# Scikit learn: TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Bunch'

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, nlp

I want to apply the *svm* using the following approach but apparently the "Bunch" type is not appropriate.

Usually, with *Bunch* (Dictionary-like object), the interesting attributes are: ‘data’, the data to learn and ‘target’, the classification labels. You can access the .data and the .target information accordingly. How can I make it work as I have the code below?

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import preprocessing

#Call the data below using scikit learn which stores them in Bunch

newsgroups_train = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='train',remove=('headers', 'footers', 'quotes'), categories = cats)
newsgroups_test = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='test',remove=('headers', 'footers', 'quotes'), categories = cats)
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer( stop_words = 'english') #new

vectors = vectorizer.fit_transform(newsgroups_train.data) #new

vectors_test = vectorizer.transform(newsgroups_test.data) #new

max_abs_scaler = preprocessing.MaxAbsScaler()
scaled_train_data = max_abs_scaler.fit_transform(vectors)#corrected
scaled_test_data = max_abs_scaler.transform(vectors_test)
clf=CalibratedClassifierCV(OneVsRestClassifier(SVC(C=1)))
clf.fit(scaled_train_data, train_labels)
predictions=clf.predict(scaled_test_data)
proba=clf.predict_proba(scaled_test_data)
```

in the `clf.fit` line in the position of "*trained_labels*" I put "*vectorizer.vocabulary_.keys*()" but it gives: `ValueError: bad input shape ()`. What should I do to get the trained labels and make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to apply a **Numerical Scaling Operation** over text data. That is logically incorrect. If you see [the official documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MaxAbsScaler.html) of `MaxAbsScalar` it's function is to :

> Scale each feature by its maximum absolute value

If you want to find the vectors of the text data, then you need to use something like `CountVectorizer`. See [this example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html#tokenizing-text-with-scikit-learn) from official documentation here.

Alternatively, you can try `TfIDfTransformer` as well. [Here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html#from-occurrences-to-frequencies) is an example of using it with newsgroup data.